# How to launch browser in kiosk mode but not full screen in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, browser

I'm creating a console application in C# which launches a browser in kiosk mode.  The problem is that it occupies the whole screen.

Is it possible for the window to be smaller and draggable?

```
launcherUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LauncherUrl"), computerName, "&UserName=" + userName);
Process.Start(ChromePath, "--kiosk " + launcherUrl);
```

This is what it looks like in full screen.
[image]

Comment: The *whole* point of Kiosk mode is to cover the whole screen and show no UI except the web page.

Comment: so not possible?

Comment: Your best bet might be to simply embed a WebBrowser control, or maybe Awesomium into your own application. That way you can have a window with decorations and still not use the browser's UI.

Comment: Why are you opening it in Kiosk mode? To remove the UI? To stop access to the desktop / other applications? Why do you need it to be draggable and not fullscreen?

Comment: I want user to not be able to access the addres bar and to be draggable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem.

Replaced:

```
Process.Start(ChromePath, "--kiosk " + launcherUrl);
```

with

```
Process.Start(ChromePath, "--app=" + launcherUrl);
```